# I want to publish a private app on google playstore that can be searched but users can't download it unless they have an invite or code

Tags: android

I want to publish a private/ invitation only app in google playstore that can be searched but users can only see it. To download the app, users would either needs to get an invite, or send an invite request, or enter a code [anything like that].

Is there a possiblity for the same? Also, what are the challenges and restrictions?

I researched about private apps and EMM api but not getting anything solid. Just wondering if some expert can help me.

Comment: it's not feasible right now private distribution is restricted to emm vendors only, I would suggest you publish the app as public and provide the enter code option on the first screen one more thing for a small user base you can use some thing like a beta testing option.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic